# Use DownloadFileTaskAsync to download all files at once

Tags: c#, task, webclient

Given a input text file containing the Urls, I would like to download the corresponding files all at once. I use the answer to this question 
[UserState using WebClient and TaskAsync download from Async CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579928/userstate-using-webclient-and-taskasync-download-from-async-ctp) as reference.

```
public void Run()
{
    List<string> urls = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/temp/Input/input.txt").ToList();

    int index = 0;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[urls.Count()];
    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string path = string.Format("{0}image-{1}.jpg", @"c:/temp/Output/", index+1);
        Task downloadTask = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), path);
        Task outputTask = downloadTask.ContinueWith(t => Output(path));
        tasks[index] = outputTask;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Start now");
    Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");

}

public void Output(string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

I expected that the downloading of the files would begin at the point of "Task.WhenAll(tasks)". But it turns out that the output look likes

```
c:/temp/Output/image-2.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-1.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-4.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-6.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-3.jpg
[many lines deleted]
Start now
c:/temp/Output/image-18.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-19.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-20.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-21.jpg
c:/temp/Output/image-23.jpg
[many lines deleted]
Done
```

Why does the downloading begin before WaitAll is called? What can I change to achieve what I would like (i.e. all tasks will begin at the same time)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> Why does the downloading begin before WaitAll is called?

First of all, you're not calling `Task.WaitAll`, which synchronously blocks, you're calling `Task.WhenAll`, which returns an awaitable which should be awaited.

Now, as others said, when you call an async method, even without using `await` on it, it fires the asynchronous operation, because any method conforming to the TAP will return a "hot task".

> What can I change to achieve what I would like (i.e. all tasks will
>   begin at the same time)?

Now, if you want to defer execution until `Task.WhenAll`, you can use `Enumerable.Select` to project each element to a `Task`, and materialize it when you pass it to `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<string> urls = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/temp/Input/input.txt");

    var urlTasks = urls.Select((url, index) =>
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string path = string.Format("{0}image-{1}.jpg", @"c:/temp/Output/", index);

        var downloadTask = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), path);
        Output(path);

        return downloadTask;
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Start now");
    await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the downloading begin before WaitAll is called?

[Because](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957):

> Tasks created by its public constructors are referred to as “cold”
>   tasks, in that they begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled
>   TaskStatus.Created state, and it’s not until Start is called on these
>   instances that they progress to being scheduled. All other tasks begin
>   their life cycle in a “hot” state, meaning that the asynchronous
>   operations they represent have already been initiated and their
>   TaskStatus is an enumeration value other than Created. **All tasks
>   returned from TAP methods must be “hot.”**

Since `DownloadFileTaskAsync` is a TAP method, it returns "hot" (that is, already started) task.

> What can I change to achieve what I would like (i.e. all tasks will begin at the same time)?

I'd look at [TPL Data Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like this (I've used `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`, but, actually, it doesn't matter):

```
    static async Task DownloadData(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        // we want to execute this in parallel
        var executionOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };

        // this block will receive URL and download content, pointed by URL
        var donwloadBlock = new TransformBlock<string, Tuple<string, string>>(async url =>
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                return Tuple.Create(url, content);
            }
        }, executionOptions);

        // this block will print number of bytes downloaded
        var outputBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, string>>(tuple =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tuple.Item2) ? 0 : tuple.Item2.Length)} bytes from {tuple.Item1}");
        }, executionOptions);

        // here we tell to donwloadBlock, that it is linked with outputBlock;
        // this means, that when some item from donwloadBlock is being processed, 
        // it must be posted to outputBlock
        using (donwloadBlock.LinkTo(outputBlock))
        {
            // fill downloadBlock with input data
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                await donwloadBlock.SendAsync(url);
            }

            // tell donwloadBlock, that it is complete; thus, it should start processing its items
            donwloadBlock.Complete();
            // wait while downloading data
            await donwloadBlock.Completion;
            // tell outputBlock, that it is completed
            outputBlock.Complete();
            // wait while printing output
            await outputBlock.Completion;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var urls = new[]
        {
            "http://www.microsoft.com",
            "http://www.google.com",
            "http://stackoverflow.com",
            "http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://www.asp.net"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Start now.");
        DownloadData(urls).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output:

> Start now.
>   Downloaded 1020 bytes from http://www.microsoft.com
>   Downloaded 53108 bytes from http://www.google.com
>   Downloaded 244143 bytes from http://stackoverflow.com
>   Downloaded 468922 bytes from http://www.amazon.com
>   Downloaded 27771 bytes from http://www.asp.net
>   Done.

Answer (score -1):

> What can I change to achieve what I would like (i.e. all tasks will
>   begin at the same time)?

To synchronize the beginning of the download you could use `Barrier` class.

```
  public void Run()
  {
      List<string> urls = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/temp/Input/input.txt").ToList();


      Barrier barrier = new Barrier(url.Count, ()=> {Console.WriteLine("Start now");} );

      Task[] tasks = new Task[urls.Count()];

      Parallel.For(0, urls.Count, (int index)=>
      {
           string path = string.Format("{0}image-{1}.jpg", @"c:/temp/Output/", index+1);
          tasks[index] = DownloadAsync(Uri(urls[index]), path, barrier);        
      })


      Task.WaitAll(tasks); // wait for completion
      Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    async Task DownloadAsync(Uri url, string path, Barrier barrier)
    {
           using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
           {
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
                await wc.DownloadFileAsync(url, path);
                Output(path);
           }
    }
```

Comment: One shouldn't use `Parallel` with TAP. E.g., look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23139769/580053. Your using of `Barrier` blocks thread and must be avoided, since this violates the principles, on which TAP is built.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, it is not scalable and less efficient than using TPL.DataFlow, yet it does not lead to deadlocks for small number of items. So why did you downvote?

Comment: @Dennis: the link you provided talks about async void, which is a different matter entirely.

Comment: Because you're using wrong tool to achieve, what OP wants, and using it wrong. I thought, that my previous comment explains this clearly, doesn't it?