# How to have my Visual Studio running without debugging program keep expanding RAM usage till RAM is full and even then use SSD as "RAM"?

Tags: windows, memory, solid-state-drive, visual-studio, c#

I got an "Out of memory exception" and my 32 GB RAM isn't even full, it's downloading pictures, I want it to keep downloading and expanding RAM usage at night and even use the SSD as alternative "RAM" after the RAM is filled (I have 2 TB SSD and it has 390 GB empty).

And why is it expanding RAM, I'm doing a loop that contains a lot of this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"g:\Folder1\" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
}
```

So why isn't the RAM being released after each time the file (image) has completed downloading.

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User

Comment: Where to post it?

Comment: You should read the tag descriptions, especially the one for C#, it indicates exactly which SE community this question would be within scope. However, it has other problems, which is one reason I am not voting to migrate it

Comment: @John1990, you can refer to the [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32391580/11507778) to know how to use WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync and Task.WhenAll to mark the wc is completed. After that you can use wc.Dispose().

Answer (score 0):

Set a [pointer to the object to *null* to encourage garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals).

That said, languages such as Java an C# that rely on garbage collection, rather than having true destructors such as C++ and Delphi (Object Pascal) that can be called explicitly, may be slow to put out the trash.

Comment: I thought that by having:
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) { }
The webclient is disposed alone, so should I add in the brackets in the end: "wc.Dispose();" and/or "wc=null;"? And I have an asyn file download operation for the WebClient and the WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted Event isn't firing, so how do I know when to dispose the WebClient wc?

Comment: Dispose of an object when done with it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574019/setting-an-object-to-null-vs-dispose